# Delete or hide default save actions/buttons

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

Me need to delete or hide the default save buttons.
I have a another custom buttons *(`$this->crud->addSaveAction(..)`)*

I tried to call this methods into `setup(){..}` from `BackpackMyController`

```
$this->crud->removeSaveAction('save_and_preview');
$this->crud->removeSaveAction('save_and_back');
$this->crud->removeSaveAction('save_and_edit');
$this->crud->removeSaveAction('save_and_new');
```

But the buttons doesn't hided.

As I understand it, the standard save_actions are added via `setupDefaultSaveActions()` from `SaveAction`-trait, which is called for example in `UpdateOperation`-trait.
The `UpdateOperation` has a `setupUpdateDefaults()` method.
It is called in the `__construct` of `CrudController` before the `setup()` method. I.e. The buttons are created in `setupDeafults()`. And in `setup()`, which I overridden, they should be removed. But it doesn't happen.

Can you tell me how to hide/delete the standard buttons ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, Backpack doesn't allow you to remove all SaveActions. If you try that, it will throw a "*Trying to access array offset on value of type null*" error. Because... without a save action, a form is not useful.

I suspect what's happened for you is that you are removing all save actions first, then adding your custom save action. I recommend switching the order:

- first do `addSaveAction()`;
- then remove all save actions you don't want, using `removeSaveAction()`;

Additionally, I recommend doing both those things in `setupCreateOperation()`, or in a method that you call in both `setupCreateOperation()` and `setupUpdateOperation()`, not in `setup()`, because that would apply to ALL operations and... not all operations have forms.